# Check if an integer function

Tags: c++

I've looked all around the place, but I can't seem to find a decent function to check if a value is an integer that isn't related to console input.

I'm looking for something like the following:

```
template <class x>
bool isInt(x){
    //if it is, return true, otherwise false.
}
```

Can someone help me out?

Note: I'm very new to C++.

Comment: Elaborate on 'is an integer'... Something like http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral?

Comment: I think you should show us how you intend to use the function. I have a hunch you actually want to parse a string...

Comment: @stijn "to check if a value is an integer" I'm sorry but I can't explain it in more detail.

Comment: @Arraying Are you trying to check it's of type `int` or it's of floating-point type and it's fractional part is equal to `0`?

Comment: as bolov says: then at least show an example of how you want to use that isInt function

Comment: @bolov I want to divide two numbers and check if the result is an integer.

Comment: @Arraying Check the quotient, i.e. `if (a % b == 0)`. Btw, your question is worded very misleading. Remove the template part and add the clarifying comment.